# Unable to require webpack config in karma.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I have a webpack config file I would like to require to use in karma.config.js.  This is the contents of the webpack config file:

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common');
const developmentConfig = require('./webpack-config/webpack.development');
module.exports = merge(commonConfig, developmentConfig, { mode: 'development' });
```

Then in my karma.config.js I attempt to require this file like so:

```
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.development');
```

However, when I run `npm run test` the console reports that \test\karma.config.js doesnt exist.  If I remove this require, it sees the file.  So far in my research this seems like it was an older known issue, however I've yet to find a valid work around.

I'm currently working with webpack 5.75.0, karma 6.4.1, and karma-webpack 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer so that posterity might know my shame.  When switching between branches where the package.json differs, always remember to `npm install` kids.  That was my issue.